# my text and content isn't being "contained" in the specified dimensions

Tags: css

```
<div id="content_container">

    <div class="inner_container">
        gffghfbvbvvbvbnvbnvnvbnvnbvnbvvnbvv

    </div>
    <div class="inner_container">
    </div>
    <div class="inner_container">
    </div>

</div>
```

the css:

```
#content_container{
position:absolute;
border:1px solid;
width:550px;
height:200px;

}

.inner_container{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:177px;
height:190px;
margin: 2px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

I swear i've done this before, so Im confused why my text is overlapping and coming out of the specified 177px dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont find any problem with your html and css its work fine.

The only problem is your text
gffghfbvbvvbvbnvbnvnvbnvnbvnbvvnbvv it have to like gffg hfbvbv vbvbnvbnvnvb nvn bvn bvvnbvv ie with white space.

if you have single word long then your defined width , then you have to use overflow:hidden

ie

```
.inner_container{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behavior when something overflows in CSS. You'll need to set the `overflow` property if you want a different behavior such as `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: scroll`.

Answer (score 1):

It's overflowing because the text is a single word with no spaces, which doesn't wrap when rendered.

What is the desired effect?  You can set `overflow: hidden;` to hide the overflowing text, or `overflow: auto;` to add a scrollbar to the div when necessary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using overflow, you can decide to let the box scroll

```
overflow:scroll;
```

or hide the rest of the text

```
overflow:hidden;
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for more details